# react native scrollView - scroll to bottom programatically

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

Im trying to scroll to end of scrollView if user chooses 'Yes' from an alert....using refs. However its not working...can anyone help?

Below is code for scrollView component opening tag

```
<ScrollView
  ref={ref => {this.scrollView = ref;}}>
```

Below is code elsewhere in class

```
      Alert.alert(
        'Scroll to end?',
        [
          {
            text: 'No',
            style: 'cancel',
          },
          {
            text: 'Yes',
            onPress: () => {
              this.scrollView.scrollToEnd();
            },
          },
        ],
      );
```

Comment: You're using functional component or class component?

Answer (score 0):

It should work in your implementation.

My return statement in render function looks like this

```
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Button title={'2-Button Alert'} onPress={this.createTwoButtonAlert} />
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollView}
          ref={ref => {this.scrollView = ref;}}>  // here is ref to my scroll view
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
            
          </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
```

This is my Alert, where I was able to scroll to the bottom using ref

```
    Alert.alert('Alert Title', 'My Alert Msg', [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      { text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.scrollView.scrollToEnd() },
    ]);
```

Take a look at a fully working example [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@pieamo/scroll-to-bottom-programmatically-on-scrollview-class-component).

Not sure where are things breaking in your code. Use this as a reference.
Maybe, providing more code may help us figure out the problem.